# Repositioning an Image on Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, collision

I'm making a flappy bird-esque game on swift and am having trouble resetting the character once it hits an object or the ceiling. Usually it's not an issue because it will just restart where it last left off. However, when it hits a high object or the ceiling, it gets stuck because the character immediately moves up and continues to hit the ceiling infinitely, causing you to have to close and restart the game.

What line of code do I need to reset it's position automatically upon collision? Thanks!

Comment: Not a single line of code on what you use for respawn. Could you give the respawn code so we see what's wrong with it ?

Comment: You don't provide any code but, walking through it verbally, I would create a `didCollide` bool flag and also save the coords of the starting position in the character's class and when `didCollide` evaluates to true, and you need to reset the game, position the character at the saved coords and set `didCollide` to false again.